# Debugging Monitor.Enter, Monitor.Exit. How?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, multithreading

Is there anyway to see what objects have had locks placed on them in the visual studio IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any method to know which objects has lock placed on them, but with [SOSAssist](http://www.thinktecture.com/SOSAssist) you can see how many locks are held by a thread.

There may be a way to see this inside the Visual Studio IDE with sos.dll, but it will probably easier to use SOSAssist.